# MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int';

Tags: ajax

I am calling a delete function from jax and I get an error message:

MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{1}"]

```js
function removeEmployee(employeeId) {
   console.log("removeEmployee " + employeeId);
   id = parseInt(employeeId);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/delete/{'+ id +'}',
      
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log ("ajax success ");
        },
        error: function() {
           console.log ("ajax failed ");
        }
    });

}
```

'''

```
@DeleteMapping(path="/delete/{id}")
public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int id) {
    System.err.println("deleting ");
    employeesRepository.deleteById(id);
    return "/index";
}
```

'''.
I don't see where is the problem
thanks for your help
if I pass an url in the ajax query, it is a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curly braces (`{ }`) are a syntax to specify that part of the path is a parameter (a.k.a "a path parameter"). You should not specify them when sending a request, only the value you want to pass:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/delete/'+ id, // Note that the { and } are removed here
  
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log ("ajax success ");
    },
    error: function() {
       console.log ("ajax failed ");
    }
});
```